# Анимация пункта меню Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, css-animation, menu

Доброго времени суток, господа!

Не могли бы вы подсказать как реализовать выделение активного раздела меню на сайте. В качестве ориентира я выбрал вот этот пример http://bayguzin.ru/demo2016/synthetica/

Использую стандартное меню bootstrap без критических изменений. Изменения касаются лишь внешнего вида: ширина, цвет.

Был бы крайне благодарен любому наброску реализации выделения меню как на примере, только выделение мне необходимо сверху.

Уважаемая [Elena](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/212421/elena) привела фрагмент кода для реализации такого подчеркивания снизу, я не совсем понимаю что можно изменить, что бы оно стало выделением сверху :D

Заранее благодарю!

Пример кода Elena:

```css
.nav>li>a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -1px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #7AE2DE;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}

.custom-menu.navbar .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, 
.custom-menu.navbar .navbar-nav>li>a:hover{
  color: #7AE2DE;
}

.custom-menu .nav>li>a:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-default custom-menu" >
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.nav>li>a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 1px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #7AE2DE;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}

.custom-menu.navbar .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, 
.custom-menu.navbar .navbar-nav>li>a:hover{
  color: #7AE2DE;
}

.custom-menu .nav>li>a:hover:before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-default custom-menu" >
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

просто в первом стиле заменить bottom:-1px на top:1px (ну и after на before - но это дело вкуса). Но как по мне выделение сверху менее очевидно и "красиво" =)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Согласен с вами, но к сожалению мой заказчик почему то уперся в идею выделения сверху -_-